# What would be a good objective function for a computer vision model that predicts rotation?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, backpropagation, computer-vision, circular-statistics

Let's say I have to correct images of scenes which can be rotated in the range $[0, 2\pi)$. For my particular application I already know a CNN makes sense. I'd use this to detect the orientation, then apply the appropriate correction. I'm just trying to think of how to frame the problem and objective function. This [blog post](https://d4nst.github.io/2017/01/12/image-orientation/) mentions the use of categorical cross-entropy loss with a multi-label classification problem where the labels are $\{0, 1, 2, 3, ... 359\}$. To me this doesn't make much sense because if the target is 45, then 44 is penalised just as hard as 87.

Regression feels a lot more sensible, apart from the fact that here the number line wraps back around onto itself. But, since max-pooling works with back-propagation I don't see why I can't use a modified MSE like $min((y-\hat{y})^2, (y-\hat{y}-2\pi)^2, (\hat{y}-y+2\pi)^2)$.

Another potential solution could be to go for the categorical approach, but apply a gaussian smoothing to the target probabilities, centered around the target label.

Would anyone care to comment or advise?

Comment: Just to confirm, you actually want to detect the degree to which an image was rotated vs. another? Or you want to do some other task, but want to make sure you get a model that is invariant to rotations? In the latter case, there's also the option of having an additional training loss (that the pooled embedding for two rotated versions of the image should be the same - i.e. at each step you don't just process a batch of images, but also of randomly rotated versions and besides the main objective, you also have this second objective).

Comment: @Björn that's quite a cool way of getting rotational invariance and I'll file that away, but yes I was going for the former question not the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach is to have the neural network output $u, v$ representing the angle $\hat \theta$ such that $\cos(\hat \theta) = \frac{u}{u^2+v^2}$, $\sin(\hat \theta) = \frac{v}{u^2+v^2}$. This avoids "boundaries" in the output which might prove challenging for backprop to learn.

Each rotation $\theta$ has a corresponding rotation matrix, which, conveniently, can be constructed with the sin and cosine of the angle.
$$R = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta\\ 
\end{array}
\right]$$

Let $\hat R$ be the rotation matrix corresponding to the predicted angle, and $R$ be the true rotation matrix. Then $\text{tr}(R^T\hat R) = 2\cos (\hat \theta - \theta)$ is useful for computing the cosine distance loss. Conveniently, this trace trick also works for 3D rotations, even if the rotation happens along more than one coordinate axis.

Comment: I ended up unaccepting the other answer and accepting this instead. @KeesMulder's answer didn't work out for me, and I suspect it's because of the multiple minima in the objective function but I haven't proven it rigorously. Using vanilla MSE worked decently even with the issue of a circular objective. Sure the loss sometimes spiked up during training, but overall the effect was averaged away. As such I was motivated to try this approach, but with a 2D MSE loss (therefore doing away with the circular objective). It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

In circular statistics, your suggestion $\min((y−\hat{y})^2,(y−\hat{y}−2π)^2,(\hat{y}−y+2π)^2), $ which we could call arc distance loss, is actually one of the known loss functions that can be used. It works, and intuitively it is certainly more sensible than the categorical approach, for the reason you mention. The reason that it is still used, I suppose, is that it circumvents treating the predictions as circular entirely.

A possibly simpler and more common approach in the field of circular statistics is to use $1 - \cos(y - \hat{y}),$ which we can call the cosine distance loss, and which ranges between 0 (when $y = \hat{y}$) and 2 (when $y = \hat{y} + \pi).$

The arc distance loss is related to the Wrapped Normal distribution; the cosine distance loss is related to the von Mises distribution. Of course, other loss functions on the circle (and hypersphere, for that matter) are conceivable, and used, such as analogues of absolute error loss.

Comment: Ahh thanks! I use cosine distance often but as a similarity metric between two unit vectors in some feature embedding space. I didn't think to apply it here.

Comment: Yes, that's right. This loss is behaves just like cosine distance (often also called cosine similarity),  except that it simplifies because we only have unit vectors here.